# How to implement Caching in Java WebApplication

Tags: java, caching, web-applications

I have Java spring based web application where i am fetching static information from Database and using it in my application. 
How to implement caching in this scenario so that i can fetch these details earlier and keep it in cache for usage ?

I want to store these details on server startup or application startup.
I need to keep refreshing these details periodically with new data if there is any data change in DB.

Server - Weblogic

I am aware that i can store this in HashMap and use it. But how to periodically keep refreshing it ? Is there any better way to implement this now ?

Comment: Seems duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747093/implementing-a-periodically-refreshing-cache-in-java

Comment: See also for reference if useful ; https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/